# Error trying to list files in directory using the ls -la command

Tags: powershell

So this command I'm trying to use to list all the files in my directory (my github repo that I cloned to vsc) doesn't seem to work. Vsc is on the latest version.

```
PS C:\VSCode\Git\test> ls -la
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter 
name 'la'.
At line:1 char:4
+ ls -la
+    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], 
ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware `-l` and `-a` (or their combo `-la`) are options of the **bash** command `ls`, **not** the PowerShell command `ls`.

Comment: It seems like you've got some form of alias translating `ls` into `Get-ChildItem`. It may be that it doesn't support the `-la` parameters

Comment: So I opened the directory using Git Bash and tried the same command and it works there.

Comment: Using the Get-ChildItem shows the list of files EXCEPT the hidden files (in this case what I'm looking for is the .git file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Powershell on Windows. In Powershell on Windows, `ls` is an alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2). It is not the `ls` command as provided on *nix.

Use one of the following commands instead.

```
Get-ChildItem -Force
```

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes Normal, Directory, Hidden
```

(Note that this is not a git issue and not a Visual Studio Code issue.)

Comment: Works by using Get-ChildItem -Attributes Hidden, Archive

Comment: @vibhav950 The Archive attribute means that a file has been backed up. Although they will often produce the same results, `-Attributes Normal, Directory, Hidden` and `-Attributes Hidden, Archive` are not the same.